# NAO Robot: suspicious beep on ALTextToSpeech

Tags: nao-robot

I get a suspicious short (100ms ?) beep sound after every phrase (stringToSay) executed with:

```
void ALTextToSpeechProxy::say(const std::string& stringToSay);
```

I get it only on my newer V6 robot, not on the old one V5. I have experienced it when running C++ compiled module, but the phenomenon may be easily observed even with the following simple .py code, executed on the robot. It's like after "hello" comes a short break and then a beep.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import qi
import sys

def main(session):
    tts = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
    tts.say("hello")

session = qi.Session()    
session.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9559")
main(session)
```

Comment: Which language is your NAO speaking? Is it doing the beep in another language?

Comment: As of the above example in Python, there is not language change and the default language is kept - English.

Comment: Kindly find enclosed a recording of the beep: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n11i52bj9bqedib/Voice%20002_sd.m4a

Comment: This sound is meant to be played when the speech recognition (ASR) finishes. There is probably an interference between your use of TTS and the ASR. Do you run topics with `ALDialog` or subscribe to it, while you call the TTS? Or a Choregraphe dialog box? What happens if you don't?

Comment: Also, are you running something like the basic channel dialog in the background?

Comment: All I do is the following:
1. Boot robot.
2. Run the above python code.

Comment: The actual above recording was captured with the following code:
(...)
main(session)
time.sleep(1)
main(session)
time.sleep(1)
main(session)
main(session)
time.sleep(1)
main(session)
main(session)
main(session)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved the BEEP problem by simply upgrading the original NAOqi 2.8.4.2 to the latest version 2.8.6.23. I did it with robot_settings app.

Answer (score 0):

Could anybody tell me if one observes a beep following the word "hello" when running the enclosed simple code on one's robot? The NAOqi version I'm running is 2.8.4.2.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import qi
import sys

session = qi.Session()    
session.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9559")
tts = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
tts.say("hello")
```